# FileServlet (BalusC's Solution) not showing save dialog in IE

Tags: java, internet-explorer, jsf, primefaces, openfiledialog

I am currently creating a JSF application with Primefaces. I am serving files from a database and I am using BalusC's FileServlet solution found on his blog.

My issue is happening in IE. When I click the download link my browser flashes and nothing happens. It however works great in firefox.

I have tried changing the Content-Disposition header from "attachment" to "inline" just to see if it would have any difference. It in firefox but again failed to do anything in IE.

Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the solution: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/07/fileservlet.html

Comment: Uhm, how about linking to the solution you are writing about?

Comment: tag `BalusC` missing :)

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd sorry I updated it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ensure that you're using standard JSF `<h:outputLink>` or just plain HTML `<a>` link to call it and not some JavaScript/Ajax-flavored PrimeFaces `<p:commandLink>` or so. It needs to be a plain vanilla HTTP GET request, not a JavaScript/Ajax-controlled request.

Comment: This probably means you are a lege now BalusC :)

Comment: Yea that was the problem. Well done thank you very much @BalusC

Comment: You can still use the <p:commandLink> (especially if you want styling).  You just have to use the ajax=false parameter.  Good luck.

Comment: @dham: as far as I recall, the `p:commandLink` has no additional styling. But you're right that you can turn off the ajax magic by `ajax="false"` **attribute**.